# Netbeans shutdown without reason

Tags: java, netbeans

Betbeans Close inmediatelly when I pass the mouse over the button "run"
I have changed java sdk version, 7,7.x 8, etc, 32bits 64bits, 
also I have tried with many versions of netbeans, 32 or 64, always is the same, 
[image: description of the problem]
I have an old netbeans 6 that works with a java sdk 6, and it works, but I cannot work with that old at until now,  I dont know why netbeans 7.x or 8.x chashes without reason with java 7.x or 8.x,

info of my pc:
windows 8.1 Pro
Processor AMD Sempron(tm)
64 bit 
the log file of netbeans has not the reason, but it is here just in case:
http://pastebin.com/rMeQ3KAz

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an undefinable bug in NetBeans called "[JVM crashes upon showing tool-tip with AMD/ATI graphics card](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138629)". 
It's not a java related issue. It is a graphics driver related issue. Therefore, it cannot be fixed within NetBeans or JVM. The solution is to install fixed driver and try again.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot find related info, I dont know if is a problem of netbeans or java sdk